# C# MD5.ComputeHash format

Tags: c#, md5

I'm using the C# code:

```
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    using (var fStream = File.OpenRead(fFile))
    {
        string Hash = BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(fStream));
        fStream.Close();
        return Hash;
    }       
}
```

The format of the output is like this:

> 41-D5-43-13-08-23-DE-18-71-56-A5-BA-46-55-0B-CF

I also used a hash program called rehash from MIT (I think)
ReichlSoft Hash Calculator (http://www.reichlsoft.de.vu) that formats the hash like this:

> 41D54313 0823DE18 7156A5BA 46550BCF

I want to be able to use the C# code instead of the rehash console application. How can I achieve the same hash format as the rehash console application so I can compare from the legacy files?

Comment: maybe don't use `BitConverter.ToString` if you don't like the format it puts it in? Or strip out the hypens/add spaces manually?

Comment: `md5.ComputeHash` returns a `Byte[]`. Instead of using `BitConverter`, simply format it yourself (e.g. with `ToString("X2")`) in groups of 4.

Comment: You don't need to call `fStream.Close` since it will be closed at the end of the `using` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use some help method to format your string:

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba, int delimiter)
{
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
    int count = 0;
    foreach (byte b in ba)
    {
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        count++;
        if (count % delimiter == 0)
        {
            hex.Append(" ");
        }
    }
    return hex.ToString().ToUpper().Trim();
}
```

And call it :

```
ByteArrayToString(md5.ComputeHash(fStream), 4)
```

Comment: This adds an additional space at the end. (should be easy to fix)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer  Thanks, i haven't seen that, i have just added Trim to the whole string,

Answer (score 1):

You can always just do this:

```
Hash = Hash.Replace("-", "");
           .Insert(7, " ")
           .Insert(16, " ")
           .Insert(25, " ");
```

Comment: That would result in `41D543130823DE187156A5BA46550BCF`, not `41D54313 0823DE18 7156A5BA 46550BCF` (no spaces)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer what's the difference? Anyway, the hash is the *bytes*, not the way you format them as strings. If you want to group the characters there are many ways to do it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The way you format them is the entire point of this question.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I thought it was obvious, but I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public String GetHash(string fFile)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();   

    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var fStream = File.OpenRead(fFile))
        {
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(fStream);
            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));

            fStream.Close();
        }    
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
public bool Compare(string hash1, string hash2)
{
    return Regex.Replace(hash1, @"\s+", "") == Regex.Replace(hash2, @"\s+", "");
}
```